Difficulty Adjusting CSS Properties and Hiding Elements Containing Specific Text
Description:
I'm encountering challenges with adjusting CSS properties and hiding specific elements on my website. Here are the main issues I'm facing:

Adjusting CSS Properties:


I need to modify the CSS properties for the .mega-menu__list class on my website. Specifically, I want to change the grid-template-columns, list-style, and padding properties. I want to adjust these properties to ensure that the menu items are positioned correctly and visually appealing.


Hiding Elements with Specific Text:


I want to hide certain elements within the .kikiki.Details-HeaderMenu-6 container that contain the text 'outlet'.

I've tried several approaches, including JavaScript and CSS, but none of them seem to work as expected. Can someone provide guidance or suggest an alternative solution to address these issues effectively?
// Hide Outlet Menu Items
    const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.mega-menu__link');
    console.log('Total menu items:', menuItems.length);
    menuItems.forEach(menuItem => {
        if (menuItem.textContent.includes('outlet')) {
            menuItem.style.display = 'none';
            menuItem.style.width = '0';
        }

// Define the function to adjust CSS properties for the mega-menu__list class
function adjustCSSProperties() {
    const targetElement = document.querySelector('.mega-menu__list');

    if (targetElement) {
        // Adjust grid-template-columns property
        targetElement.style.gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))';

        // Adjust list-style property
        targetElement.style.listStyle = 'none';

        // Adjust padding property
        targetElement.style.padding = '2.4rem 0';
    } else {
        console.error('Target element .mega-menu__list not found.');
    }
}

I want to adjust these properties to ensure that the menu items are positioned correctly and visually appealing.

What exactly goes wrong? Does anything happen? Are you getting errors?

It appears that the new CSS properties are not adjusting as intended based on my code. Despite implementing the adjustments, the position of the items remains unchanged, and I have not encountered any errors during the process.

So your code runs, and you can verify that the CSS has been updated; have you used the browser inspector tool to see what it thinks about the CSS state for the affected elements? It generally tells you everything about the styles being applied for any element.

Visually appealing can mean a lot of things (eye of the beholder and all that). Would it be possible for you to edit your question and post an image of how your website looks?
